# Backbonejs updating Model with idAttribute set to Id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, backbone.js

I'm trying to update a backbone model, the server side is asp.net mvc 4. I'm getting:

> "System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added" exception.

The reason is because backbone is sending Id and id to the server as properties, and the **JsonValueProvider** tries to add this to a dictionary.

Here is my model:

```
 var Task = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url: "/tasks/task",
        idAttribute: "Id"
 });
```

This is send to the server via Put request:

```
{"Id":294912,"Task":"test","DueDate":"2012-03-24T02:00:00.000Z", "id":294912}
```

Is there a way to prevent backbone in sending the "id" property?

Comment: What is your code that is "updating" the model? Are you sure you're not trying to create a model that already exists?

Comment: Pretty sure. The problem is with the JsonValueProvider

Comment: what happens if you set `idAttribute` to `"id"` instead? Duplicate or are they merged (i think that they are merged)?

Comment: I am setting the idAttribute to Id because the data returned from the server side is using Id. If I don't then when loading my collections the "id" is never set. I know the easy answer would be to have the data returned a lower case "id" but there is already a lot of it, I'm looking at how the data gets serialized to json, I see JSON.NET can camelcase property names when serializing.

Comment: That makes sense. If you can drop in your own `JsonValueProvider` this whole problem goes away.

Comment: This wasnt the issue I had, but lead me to find that I had two properties being posted by Backbone as the "defaults" hash had one field with a different casing than being used to hydrate the model. This lead me to more closely look at the posted JSON. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is because the conventions in C# is not the same as in JavaScript. In C# classes have properties that starts with capital letters (Pascal Case) and it's the norm in JavaScript to start your properties in lower case (Camel Case).

Thus when serializing view models the default behavior of the JSON.NET serializer is to serialize the object exactly with the same capitalization of properties. I could rename the properties on the view model to be camel case, but it would be as "weird" as to have properties with pascal case in your JavaScript objects.

So instead to force Backbone into a non convention way, I've change the serialization of the objects to convert the Pascal case properties into Camel case properties by leveraging [JSON.NET's Contract Resolver](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/ContractResolver.html) functionality.

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
JsonSerializer serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object, Formatting.None, settings);
```

Now this creates consistency on the client side with my code and with all the cool libraries out there.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like the issue is in your server-side code, not with the call from Backbone. A `PUT` is an edit operation on the server, so you're updating an existing entity. You need the ID property to identify the model on the server and update the properties that have changed.

If ASP.NET MVC is complaining that the model already exists in the database, you are trying to do an `INSERT` instead of an `UPDATE`. We'd need to see the controller and data access code to see where things are going awry.

**UPDATE**: What happens if you leave off the `idAttribute` property? From the Backbone documentation:

```
A special property of models, the id is an arbitrary string (integer id or UUID). 
If you set the id in the attributes hash, it will be copied onto the model as a 
direct property.
```

The `id` attribute should be sent by default; it looks like you're forcing it to be included a second time.

Under `idAttribute` in the docs:

```
A model's unique identifier is stored under the id attribute. If you're directly communicating 
with a backend (CouchDB, MongoDB) that uses a different unique key, you may set a Model's 
idAttribute to transparently map from that key to id.
```

ASP.NET MVC's model binding should be able to cope with `id` vs. `Id`.

UPDATE: Found a good [blog post](http://codedoc.zocdoc.com/client-server-data-persistence-with-backbone-js-and-net-mvc) that describes using a view model to aid in serializing your C# objects into the format Backbone expects. This seems like a reasonable, if slightly annoying, solution.

Comment: The action is not even being execute yet nor the database. The issue is with the JsonValueProvider, updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC viewmodels are serialized to the client with a property of "Id", if I don't set the idAttribute then my backbone models does not have the "id" property set, that is why I am using idAttribute.  ASP.NET MVC model binding is not case sensitive looks like it, so now my backbone models have an "Id" and "id" property which get sent to the server when I do Model.save()

Comment: Updated my answer with a link.

Comment: Found a better solution in that json serialization should return camel case properties. Will update question/answer.